# Hide a digital values

Tags: jquery

I write a filter and now I have a problem with hiding digital values
This is a code of filter html:

```
<div class="height" th:classappend="${model.height}">some information</div>

<div class="searchColor" id="filterHeight">
    <div class="searchTextColor"> Height:</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="27" value="2.7-2.9m" />2,7-2,9m<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="29" value="2.9-3.0m"/>2,9-3,0m<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="30" value="3.0-3.15m"/>3,0-3,15m<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="315" value="3.15m"/>>3,15m&nbsp;
</div>
```

I write this filter, this filter works if `class` is string, but I don't understand why it's not working if number + string?

```
$("div[class='searchColor'] input").change(function () {
    if($("#filterHeight input:checked").length > 0){
        $('.height').show();

    $("#filterHeight input:not(:checked)").each(function() {
        var selectedStr = $(this).val();
        $('.height' + selectedStr).hide();
    });
```

I need `if` becouse I use several conditions

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that the values in your checkbox inputs have periods '.', which will be interpreted by jQuery as a class deliminator.

So for your line:

```
$('.height' + selectedStr).hide();
```

Might get executed like:

```
$('.height2.7-2.9m').hide();
```

But jQuery looks at that string and breaks it apart by the periods, so instead of looking for elements that are of class '.height2.7-2.9m' it looks for elements that have all the classes '.height2', '.7-2', and '.9m'.

Try removing dots from the checkbox value names (and from the classes you're trying to match in the HTML)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried use html `value` without dots and comma, but unfortunately it's not working. I recive from DB this height, I can use ',' or '.' , but without dot or comma people can't understand height